# How to implement two or more functions on Click event in React & ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

In the case of this code, I have to click the calculate button twice to find answers of BMI and BMI judge. How to code it to click only once find the two answers?

```
bmiCalc (){
    this.setState({bmi:this.state.weight/(this.state.height*this.state.height)*10000});


    if(this.state.bmi<18.5){this.setState({judge: 'Underweight'});}
    else if(this.state.bmi<24.9){this.setState({judge:'Normal weight'});}
    else if(this.state.bmi<30){this.setState({judge:'Overweight'});}
    else{this.setState({judge:'Obesity'});}
}


render(){
    return (
        <ul><button onClick={this.bmiCalc.bind(this)}>calculate</button></ul>
        <ul>BMI: {Math.round(this.state.bmi*10)/10}</ul>
        <ul>BMI judge :{this.state.judge} </ul>
    );
}
```

Comment: Please put your code in your question. Or use links at least!!!

Comment: ps, BMI is a bunch of bullsh!t.

Comment: Your JSX syntax is invalid. `render()` returns multiple elements, they're not an array, not even separated by commas. Not to mention that React forbids `render()` from returning multiple root elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by calling the set state once at the end of your function:

```
bmiCalc() {
    const bmi = this.state.weight/(this.state.height*this.state.height)*10000;
    let judge = 'Obesity';
    if(this.state.bmi<18.5){this.setState({judge: 'Underweight'});}
    else if(this.state.bmi<24.9){this.setState({judge:'Normal weight'});}
    else if(this.state.bmi<30){this.setState({judge:'Overweight'});}

    this.setState({bmi: bmi, judge: judge});
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is of some help. [codehere](https://jsfiddle.net/uraway/gyxj4nor/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
function desiredActions (){
  action1()
  action2()
}

<button onclick={desiredActions}></button>
```

Basically just wrap the functions you want to call in a function and assign it to the onclick handler.

Note: this isn't specific to React or ES6, just basic JavaScript.